# I have a problem with pressing a button by xpath using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, button, click

I want to press a button with the XPath of

```
//*[@id="rass-action-proceed"]
```

i don't know how to use selenium. can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to do so using the respective XPath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="rass-action-proceed"]')
elem.click() # Using WebElements 'click()' method for sheer simplicity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("rass-action-proceed").click()
```

or with Explicit wait :

```
WebDriverWait(driver , 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "rass-action-proceed"))).click()
```

**make sure to import :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: then i get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: try the updated code with ID instead of xpath.